# revert the changes on the click event of cancel button

Tags: asp.net-4.0

I have a User control(UserInformation.ascx)  with several controls like text boxes,raddatepicker,list boxes ,etc.
I need that if a user makes any changes and then clicks cancel the initial values should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about retrieving the original page via AJAX and updating all the original values?

```
<script>
  $("#myCancelButton").on("click", function () {
    $.get({
      url: document.location.href,
      success: function(result) {
        $("input", $(result)).each(function(index, el) {
          var originalElement = $("#" + $(el).attr("id"));
          $(el).val(originalElement.val());
        });
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Prkh No problem, welcome to StackOverflow. If it works, mark it as correct so that other's will benefit and so that I get sweet sweet points.